# Hide iframe if src is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I work for a school system http://m.rsd17.org/index1.html and working on an annoucement to show up for school cancellations.  I have an external page that I uncomment and change the text if there is a delay or schools closed.  On the top of my site I want to hide the iframe if I comment out the writing from the external file.  Here is some of the code Im using.

```
<iframe id="emergency" src="http://f.rsd17.org/frontemergency1.html" width="100%" height="50px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I want it to show the iframe when I haven't commented out the text in the external html.  And I want it the iframe totally gone so the buttons move back up when there is no message to display.  I've tried a bunch of different jquery scripts, but no luck removing the iframe when the html is empty.  Any thoughts would be great.

Comment: It would likely be easier to use ajax to get the content of that html page and append it to a certain location, then, when the page is empty, nothing will be appended.

Comment: If the iFrame shows content from the same domain, you can initially hide it, once it's loaded you can check that it has content, and if it does, show it.

Comment: or you could pull it with SSI instead of in an iframe. is SSI enabled on the server?

Comment: use ssi is enabled.  I use it on all my normal pages, for some reason I can't get it to work on this one.  <div id="frontemergency"><!--#include file="frontemergency.html"--></div>  thats what I use for my non mobile site.  Might be I have the path set wrong.  The mobile website is in a folder inside my full site.

Comment: That would be because the mobile is `html` files and the full site is `shtml` files. you can enable ssi on `html`, but by default it works on `shtml`. http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess4.shtml should help with the settings.

Comment: something like `../file.name` will take the path back one directory, but you should use the full path in ssi if it's not inside, or won't always be inside, the current directory, like `/var/www/site/file.name`

Comment: or just make the main index file for the mobile `index.shtml` instead of `index.html` to get ssi working. if you don't want to change the htaccess settings.

Comment: yea we are running a windows server and not an apache, so i'll see what I can do tomorrow.  thanks for the tips forgot that it had to be shtml for ssi.  brains fried from doing the normal site and the mobile site.

Comment: No problem. If you ever want to switch them to responsive site using drupal, so you have one site and an easy way to update everything from your phone, let me know. Drupad makes that easy http://drupad.com/

Comment: K I got it to work by moving the file inside my mobile folder.  But I need it on the outside of the folder.  The way I have my two websites set up is there is a www folder which holds everything, inside the www folder is a folder called mobile.  That's where I am holding my mobile files.  any thoughts how I need to do the ssi to get to the folder outside mobile.  I tried <!--#include file="../frontemergency1.html"-->, but it didn't work.  and does it matter that my full site is www.rsd17.org and my mobile site is m.rsd17.org?

Comment: I think I fixed it, just moved the include file inside the mobile folder and changed my main page to find the correct file.  thanks for your help filever10

Comment: awesome, no problem. glad it worked! you would want to use the path from root instead of ../. on windows server it would be like `C:\path\to\site\file.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue but using SSI, changing the index.html to index.shtml, and moving the file I was using to the correct folder.  Changed my links on my main index.shtml.  All is better.  Thank you FiLeVeR10 for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server PHP-enabled? I ask because if this is for a school district you may not want to assume that all users will have javascript enabled, etc. It might be best to handle this on the back end where users are not dependent on their browser being capable.

Inside `http://f.rsd17.org/frontemergency1.php`:

```
<?php
die(); //Comment this out to display a message
?>
Announcement here!
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to check if there is a content in your iframe. If you put a comment-content then your iframe will encapsulate and display it. If you delete the comment then your iframe will still be there but it will not be visually noticeable.

Although you do not need this, you can try something like this with jQuery:

```
var html_content = $('#emergency ').find('#alertmessagebox').children().html();
if(html_content[0] === '' ) {

    $('#emergency').css('display','none');

} else {

    $('#emergency').css('display','');          

}
```

Comment: If I comment out the external file it doesn't show anything, but there is a huge gap where the iframe is.  I want that gap to be gone as well.  Almost like I delete the iframe.

Comment: If so then use the code i gave you above. It should work fine.